# Unable to run my HTML code in google chrome

Tags: php, html, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google charts and integrate in my android app. Before that I tried to check my html code in Google chrome. In that code I have tried to integrate to get the data from the MYSQL. 
My code as follows

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";  
    $database = "mobiledb";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password)
    or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);



$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `x-axis` AND `y-axis` LIMIT 0, 30 ");

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$arr2=array_keys($x-axis);
$arr1=array_values($y-axis);
}
for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
{
    $chart_array[$i]=array((string)$arr2[$i],intval($arr1[$i]));
}
echo "<pre>";
$data=json_encode($chart_array);
?>

<html>
  <head>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

      $(function () {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn("string", "x-axis");
        data.addColumn("number", "y-axis");
         data.addRows(<?php $data ?>);
    });         
         var options = {
           title: 'Details',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to see the graph. And I was getting the following error  **"; $data=json_encode($chart_array); ?>** And when I inspect the page I was found the following error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < **  Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is within this line `data.addRows(<?php $data ?>);` It needs to be `data.addRows(<?php echo($data);?>);`.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to copy the source of the rendered page as well as the PHP you have here.

Comment: you have a `<pre>` tag before your html, that can also be causing problems like not rendering the page but showing the html instead

Comment: No it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Navigate to the page in a browser, then right click and select "View Page Source", then copy the page source into your question.

Comment: It is the same code I got

Comment: No, that's your server side code. The error you are experiencing is somewhere within your Javascript (client side scripting language). If you are running this locally, then you need to find it's URL probably something like `localhost/your_app_name/your_filename.php`. At this point, right click and select view source. That is the bit we need to see to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to correct this line probably

```
data.addRows(<?php $data ?>); //incorrect 
data.addRows(<?php echo($data); ?>); //you forgot to echo it
```

There are so many problem with your `PHP` code

```
  //what is this?
  $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `x-axis` AND `y-axis` LIMIT 0, 30 ");

  //probably you want this?
  $sth = mysql_query("SELECT `x-axis`, `y-axis` FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 30 ");

  //this is wrong 
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $arr2=array_keys($x-axis);
    $arr1=array_values($y-axis);
  }

  //try this 
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $arr2=array_keys($r['x-axis']);
    $arr1=array_values($r['y-axis']);
  }

 //where  is $chart_array defined? It should be like this 
 $chart_array = array();
 for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
 {
     $chart_array[$i]=array((string)$arr2[$i],intval($arr1[$i])); 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice but still it has showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

check your query

```
 $sth = mysql_query("SELECT `x-axis`,`y-axis`  FROM `table`  LIMIT 0, 30 ");
```

if you want  column  x-axis and y-axis then use this

then correct this

```
  data.addRows(<?php echo $data ?>);
```

Comment: I want only those two columns

Comment: I was getting the white screen and when I try to inspect the elements I was able to see this error " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < g1.html:44  "